# What determines CPU cycle time

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cycles

I'd like to find out whether there is a relationship between CPU cycle time and pipeline depth. I have always thought that CPU cycle time is entirely determined by CPU frequency (opposite to frequency). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk34qSnMcV4), however, mentions that with a larger number of pipeline stages the cycle time can be decreased since every cycle we would do less work per stage. So what actually determines the CPU cycle time: the frequency or the number of stages in the pipeline? Or can we say that pipeline depth affects the frequency?

Comment: For high-performance microprocessor designs, it's often the latency of the ALUs that determines the cycle time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cycle time is literally defined as the inverse of frequency.  This is just basic physics: `f = 1/t` where `t` is the period.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency#Period_versus_frequency.  Frequency has dimensions of `1/seconds`.

Saying you can shorten the cycle time by lengthening the pipeline is just another way of stating the same thing as raising the frequency.

(And yes, chopping up one stage into two means you have two shorter critical paths instead of one long one that has to be ready before the end of a cycle to get latched for the next stage, removing that upper limit on cycle time.  For a given gate delay propagation time, you can only fit a certain number of boolean operations into one clock cycle, and every stage has to have its output ready in time.)

See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/)